# Memory issue with data viewer application C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My application is a data viewer, so it's comprised of rows and columns, with individual cells (think Excel).

Let me describe my data structure a bit. A dataset is a collection of columns. Each column has a collection of cells. Each cell has bound to it a VariableContent class which you can see below.

```
object _content;
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the content of the cell
/// </summary>
public object Content {
    get {
        return (_content);
    }
    set {
        _content = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Content));
    }
}

ObservableCollection<Comment> _comments;
public ObservableCollection<Comment> Comments
{
    get
    {
        return (_comments);
    }
    set
    {
        _comments = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Comments));
    }
}

Color _color = Brushes.Transparent.Color;
public Color Color
{
     get { return _color; }
    set
    {
        _color = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Color));
    }
}


public VariableContent(object Content, ObservableCollection<VariableComment> Comments, Color Color)
{
    PropertyChanged = null;
    this.Content = Content;
    this.Comments = Comments;
    this.Color = Color;
}
```

So for each cell we may store a list of comments, and a color potentially. The Comments and Color properties are new as we recently added a feature to be able to color cells, and add comments to cells.

However, I've discovered that with large datasets (e.g. hundreds of thousands of rows), since there are many cells and therefore many instances of this VariableContent class being initialized, the memory usage has gone up by roughly one third which is too much, compared to before our update where we did not have the Color and Comments property in this class. Another side effect is the loading time of a dataset has gone up by a third too.

Setting the property values to null makes no difference, only removing the properties from the class will bring the memory footprint down again. Is there something else I can do to help this?

Comment: maybe try **flyweight pattern**, and do you have to show all items in ui at once(if not, try  data virtualization)

Comment: What about only initializing/ creating the cells your user can actually see and dynamically loading/ creating more when user scrolls to see more?

Comment: I'm using virtualization actually. The ItemsControl control for the columns list, and the ItemsControl control for the cells list both have VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" and VirtualizingStackPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"

Comment: If I disabled those then the ram usage is far far higher.

Comment: Flyweight patterns sounds interesting, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

if you using large data then you need to use pagination. When paging through data, the precise records displayed in a page depend upon the page of data being requested and the number of records displayed per page. Memory usage does not increase and dataset load times will be faster. It is not good solution loading big data to ObservableCollection